# Spilt bleach on stained hardwood floor

Tags: repair, wood, floor, removal

Unfortunately upon moving into our new rented flat we have spilt a small amount of bleach (about the size of a large coin) onto hardwood floor.

Here is a picture:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/QfOIx3h.jpg]

Is there anything we can do such as re-apply varnish / screen the particular area that the bleach was spilt on and attempt to match the rest of the floor? Or will we need to completely sand it and start again?

Many thanks

Comment: Note that this was mad much worse because there looks to be nothing protecting the floors other than stain.  I would just use marker or matching stain.  In most applications and every rental I have seen you would have some sort of poly coats protecting your wood.

Comment: How long did the bleach stand?  Did you wipe it up right away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would "brighten" the bleached area with an oxalic acid based cleaner/brightner, frequently the base chemical in deck cleaners.  Neutralize with a base, like baking soda.  Once dry, try a dye or a pigmented stain.  If the color is close, seal it with a similar finish, typically a satin polyurethane.

Answer (score 0):

You might try sanding it very lightly with 240 grit sandpaper, then staining it with a light colored [stain pen](http://www.homedepot.com/s/stain%2520pens?NCNI-5)

[image: stain pen]

Buy two or three shades and start with the lightest color.

Finish it with a wipe on polyurethane (the picture looks like a satin finish)

```
Images and links for illustration only, not an endorsement of particular goods or sources.
```